# If three events are independent, are they also pairwise independent?

Tags: probability

If three events A, B, and C satisfy
$\Pr(A \cap B \cap C) = \Pr(A) \cdot \Pr(B) \cdot \Pr(C)$, does this imply that the three events also satisfy the following?

$\Pr(A \cap B) = \Pr(A) \cdot \Pr(B)$

$\Pr(B \cap C) = \Pr(B) \cdot \Pr(C)$

$\Pr(A \cap C) = \Pr(A) \cdot \Pr(C)$

Comment: The title does not correspond to the body since the body of the question assumes only that Pr(A∩B∩C)=Pr(A)⋅Pr(B)⋅Pr(C), which is strictly weaker than the independence of (A,B,C).

Comment: @Did Could you please edit the title then? I am currently learning about these concepts and am thus not sure how to properly phrase it to reflect the body.

Comment: please explain @Did as to what should the question be and why is the body strickly weaker than independence of A,B,C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

presumably if $A$ is the empty set then the first relation holds but $B$ and $C$ can be arbitrary so no.

Comment: please can you elaborate?