# If the probability of 3 events with non-zero probability equals the product of the individual probabilities, are they also pairwise independent?

Tags: probability

Consider three events $A$, $B$, and $C$, none of which has a zero probability. If $A$, $B$, and $C$ satisfy
$\Pr(A \cap B \cap C) = \Pr(A) \cdot \Pr(B) \cdot \Pr(C)$, does this imply that the three events also satisfy the following?

$\Pr(A \cap B) = \Pr(A) \cdot \Pr(B)$

$\Pr(B \cap C) = \Pr(B) \cdot \Pr(C)$

$\Pr(A \cap C) = \Pr(A) \cdot \Pr(C)$

This is a follow-up to the following question: [If three events are independent, are they also pairwise independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126264/if-three-events-are-independent-are-they-also-pairwise-independent)

Comment: There can exist non-empty events that nevertheless have zero probability, so the same sort of counterexample can be constructed as before. I recommend editing this question to disallow such events as well.

Comment: @Sal I edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Take an ordinary fair dice with six faces. Then set
$A=\{1,2,3,4\}$
$B=\{1,2,3\}$
$C=\{3,5,6\}$.

Then $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$ but $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: There is a typo: $P(A \cap B \cap B)$ should be $P(A \cap B \cap C)$.

Comment: Double typo fixed, thanks.